# Authorize attribute with roles when calling action from another action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to decorate a controller action with `[Authorize(Roles="someRole")]` attribute when this action is called from another one?

I have a set of actions. The first one (let's call it a parent action) is calling another ones (child actions). Every action can be used only by a user with a specific role.

The problem is that `FirstAction()` is called even if the logged-in user doesn't have the `"Admin"` role.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin,Editor")]
public ActionResult Details()
{
  //some code ......
  return FirstAction()
  // other actions
  return SecondAction()  
}

[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult FirstAction()
{
}
```

Is there any way to use `[Authorize]` attribute in such a case? Or the only solution is to manually check if the logged user has a specific role?

Comment: It's not appropriate to return another ActionResult and expert authorization attributes to run. Use `RedirectToAction` instead.

Comment: I guess you can just manually check using `User.IsInRole("Admin")`